# "System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException" in facebook sdk

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-3.0

I got an error when i kept a control from facebook sdk to integrate with my windows phone app. I got the reference from [this link](http://facebooksdk.net/docs/phone/). But i inserted the control and made a registered the event onSessionChanged. When i launch the app, it crashes without any interaction. The XAML code is simple.

```
<controls:LoginButton x:Name="loginButton" HorizontalAlignment="Center" SessionStateChanged="onSessionStateChanged" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" ApplicationId="MYAPPID"/>
```

The exception i got is TargetInvocationException and the inner exception is:

- InnerException  {Facebook.WebExceptionWrapper: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
  at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
  at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c_*DisplayClasse.b*_d(Object sendState)
  at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c_*DisplayClass1.b*_0(Object sendState)
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---}  System.Exception {Facebook.WebExceptionWrapper}